# onlongclick listner in android 2.0.3

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

In my java code i used `onLongClickListener` and opened 1 `AlerDailogBox` that shows delete or not!!but i want to show some options on my longclick and according to the choice i want to do further.i dont want to use context menu.plz suggest me in current code what changes should i make?

```
 OnLongClickListener myListener = new OnLongClickListener() {
                         public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {

                         // do something on long click
                         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
                         alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to Delete?");
                         alertDialog.setMessage(" "+temp_name);
                         alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                EstimateTrackerActivity.this.dh.deleteexp(inc_id);
                                /*//Toast.makeText(EstimateTrackerActivity.this, "id"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                onclick_addcategory(v);*/
                                onclick_listexpense(v);
                                spinner.setSelection(temp3);
                            }
                         });
                         alertDialog.setButton2("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                onclick_listexpense(v);
                                spinner.setSelection(temp3);
                            }
                         });
                         alertDialog.show();
                       return false;
                     }
                 };  tr_inc.setOnLongClickListener(myListener);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound from your problem, I think you are new to Android.

Ok, look at code below.

To create an `AlertDialog` with a list of selectable items like the one shown to the right, use the `setItems()` method:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

For more info look at [Creating an AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Comment: yes im new to android.sorry for asking this basic question.thanks for help.